# Is there any way to middleware router with group router?

Tags: go, beego, golang-migrate

I am beginner in beego framework, I have completed few R&D inside on it.
But I need few helps related routers.

I have created few route with middleware and group router but I need few suggestions from expert.

Let me share example which I did.

**Router.go**

```
func init() {
    ns := beego.NewNamespace("/api/v1",

        beego.NSNamespace("/front",
            beego.NSBefore(AuthFilter),
            beego.NSRouter("/user",&controllers.ObjectController{},"*:GetValueByAdmin"),
            beego.NSRouter("/test",&controllers.ObjectController{},"*:GetValueByAdmin"),
            beego.NSRouter("/test",&controllers.ObjectController{},"*:GetValueByAdmin"),
            beego.NSRouter("/test",&controllers.ObjectController{},"*:GetValueByAdmin"),
            beego.NSRouter("/product",&controllers.ObjectController{},"*:GetValueByAdmin"),
        ),


        beego.NSNamespace("/a1",
            beego.NSRouter("/test1",&controllers.ObjectController{},"*:GetValueByAdmin1"),
            beego.NSRouter("/test2",&controllers.ObjectController{},"*:GetValueByAdmin1"),
            beego.NSInclude(
                &controllers.UserController{},
            ),
        ),
    )

    beego.AddNamespace(ns)
}

var AuthFilter = func(ctx *context.Context) {
    // The Authorization header should come in this format: Bearer <jwt>
    // The first thing we do is check that the JWT exists
    header := strings.Split(ctx.Input.Header("Authorization"), " ")
    if header[0] != "Bearer" {
        ctx.Abort(401, "Not authorized")
    }
}
```

I have created router using Namespace and It is working fine using this url (http://localhost:8080/api/v1/front/test). But I want to remove "front" keyword from URL.

**I tried below options like:**

1. I copied code inside "Front" namespace to put outside but My "NSBefore" Will apply all the method which is defined after that. I need 2 group. Before auth and after auth. In after auth, I want to add `beego.NSBefore(AuthFilter)`.
2. I tried using policy but it will not work as I needed.

   `beego.Policy("/api/v1/front/*","*", AuthFilter)`
   `beego.Policy("/api/v1/admin/*","*", AuthFilter)`

If I will remove front from policy then it will apply all the URL.

Do we have any option to create group router without URL path and it will cover my concept?